# Create a button with createElement and then change it's color

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bit of script that creates a button for the user to push after certain criteria has been met.  This all works fine, but the button that is created is just the default style and I would like to change the properties of the button.  This is what I have:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
 </script>
```

I am guessing I need to use setAttribute somewhere to change properties, but I am not sure how to set this up.

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: What properties do you want to change?

Comment: It's an element in the DOM like any other. Write CSS as normal.

Comment: @Traver he obviously is not using jQuery or why would he create and append with vanilla instead making the entire element with everything using append(" element definition ")

Comment: @Quentin I think his main problem is he doesn't know to differentiate that button from other buttons. He should first add id or class to remedy that :)

Answer (score 4):

you can set style as like

```
function myFunction() {
   var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
   btn.style.color = 'red';
   document.body.appendChild(btn);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define your css already and add the button.

```css
.btn{
  color:#fff;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
Adding dynamic elements
<button type="button" onclick="add();">
Add
</button>

<script>
 function add(){
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  btn.innerHTML = "new button";
  btn.className = "btn";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the "style" field of the created element, like this:

```
btn.style.color = "#fff";
btn.style.background = "#000";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setAttribute:

```
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: black');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a class like so:

```
btn.classList.add('newClass');
```

then in CSS, add your styles:

```
.newClass
{
    color:red;
}
```

Or, you could do it all in javascript (**not preferable**):

```
btn.style.color = 'red';
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var y = document.createTextNode("Button TEXT");

  btn.style.color = '#fff';
  btn.style.background = "#F00";
  
  btn.appendChild(y);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class to your button then bind your styling in CSS.
It's a simple and possible to have styles manipulated in your JS code BUT it's considered a bad practice.

Adding a class to your element:

```
btn.className = "MyClass"; (for only 1 class)
btn.classList.add("MyClass") (if you already might have classes, seeing that you just created the element in line before)
```

insert this before you append the element into the body

then in a linked CSS file add this:

```
.MyClass{
   background:red;
}
```

If you insist on doing everything in JS you can use:

```
btn.setAttribute('style', 'background: red');
```

instead of .className and skip the CSS file

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class with the style that you wish the button to have and then :

```
btn.className = "myClass";
```

If you don't want to create a CSS class then you could also do the following:

```
btn.style.color = "pink";
btn.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

The "color" property only changes the text's color, the "backgroundColor" changes its background